# Django Forms ImageFileld

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, form, django-model

Не могу обновить профиль , добавить новые данные , сохраняет либо в виде кортежа либо ошибка , подскажите в чем дело

forms.py

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.Form):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    about= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,max_length=255)
    birthday = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
def updateprofile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            about = form.cleaned_data['about']
            birthday = form.cleaned_data['birthday']
            avatar = request.FILES.get('avatar')
            print(type(about),about)
            print(type(birthday),birthday)
            print(type(avatar),avatar)

            profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
            # profile.avatar = avatar,
            profile.about= about,
            # profile.birthday=birthday,
            profile.save()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfileForm()
    return render(request, 'updateprofile.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Можете добавить все остальные файлы или дать ссылку на гитхаб проект, чтобы можно было попробовать воспроизвести ошибку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**models**

```
from django.db import models

class Profile(models.Model):
    avatar = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    about= forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea,max_length=255)
    birthday = forms.DateField(required=False)
```

**forms**

```
class UpdateProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views**

```
class ProfileEdit(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'profiles/profile_edit.html'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        formProfile = UpdateProfileForm(instance=get_profile)
        context.update({'formProfile': formProfile})
        return self.render_to_response(context)


    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        get_profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        formProfile = UpdateProfileForm(self.request.POST,instance=get_profile)
        if formProfile.is_valid():
            formProfile.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('profile_home'))
        else:
            print('NotValid')
            return self.form_invalid(formProfile, **kwargs)

    def form_invalid(self, formProfile, **kwargs):
        context = self.get_context_data()        
        context.update({'formProfile': formProfile})
        return self.render_to_response(context)
```